# sap.m.TableSelectDialog: Customize Button Texts in the Footer

Tags: sapui5

Somehow I want to get the <kbd>Confirm</kbd> and the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button of a `TableSelectDialog` for changing the text. But I don't know how to do it properly.

In my opinion, the best solution is to set the buttons in the fragment but there are no `<buttons>` aggregations like in the `sap.m.Dialog`. So how can I set my buttons with my own text in the footer toolbar?

```xml
<TableSelectDialog xmlns="sap.m"
  noDataText="No Products Found"
  title="Select Product"
  search=".handleSearch"
  confirm=".handleClose" -> want this button
  cancel=".handleClose"  -> want this button
  multiSelect="true"
  ....
</TableSelectDialog>
```

Comment: Since 1.68, the "Confirm" button can be customized. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56792955/5846045

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are trying to change the texts of the OK and Cancel button.

In order to do that, even though I hope someone else offers a better solution, you could try the following:

1) Assign an `id` to your `TableSelectDialog`:

```
<TableSelectDialog
    noDataText="No Products Found"
    title="Select Product"
    search="handleSearch"
    confirm="handleClose"
    cancel="handleClose"
    multiSelect="true"
    id="IdTableSelectionDialog">

...

</TableSelectDialog>
```

2) Before opening the dialog try the following:

```
//Change the OK button text
sap.ui.getCore().byId("IdTableSelectionDialog")._getOkButton().setText("New value you want to use");

//Change the Cancel button text
sap.ui.getCore().byId("IdTableSelectionDialog")._getCancelButton().setText("New value you want to use");
```

Answer (score 0):

As of UI5 version **1.68.x**, `sap.m.TableSelectDialog` as well as `sap.m.SelectDialog` provides a new property called `confirmButtonText`<sup>1</sup>.

```xml
<TableSelectDialog xmlns="sap.m"
  confirmButtonText="{i18n>myOwnConfirmText}"
  ....
</TableSelectDialog>
```

However, there is currently no public API to customize the *Cancel* button. You'll have to rely on the previous solution (accessing the private API which we all strongly discourage from) or just leave the standard text which improves not only the upwards compatibility but also UI consistency across other Fiori applications.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> [`commit:5795433`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/57954336cfb6ca2c854be5ab7f1903b1e48dfc10)</sub>